# Instantiate threading within a class

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I have a `class` within a `class` and want to activate `threading` capabilities in the second `class`. Essentially, the script below is a reproducible template of my proper project.

When I use `@threading` I get that `showit` is not iterable, so the `tp.map` thinks I do not have a list.

However, when I run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tp = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
    print(tp.map(testit(id_str).test_first, id_int))
    for values in tp.map(testit(id_str).test_first, id_int):
        values
```

I get no issues, besides that I want the expected output to print out each number in the list. However, I wanted to achieve this within the class.

Something like the following:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import List

id_str = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
id_int = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def threaded(fn, pools=10):
    tp = ThreadPoolExecutor(pools)
    def wrapper(*args):
        return tp.map(fn, *args)  # returns Future object
    return wrapper

class testit:
    def __init__(self, some_list: List[str]) -> None:
        self._ids = some_list
        print(self._ids)

    def test_first(self, some_id: List[int]) -> None:
        print(some_id)

class showit(testit):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(showit, self).__init__(*args)
    
    @threaded
    def again(self):
        global id_int
        for values in self.test_first(id_int):
            print(values)

a = showit(id_str)
print(a.again())
```

Error:

```py
  File "test_1.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(a.again())
  File "test_1.py", line 10, in wrapper
    return tp.map(fn, *args)  # returns Future object
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 600, in map
    fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
TypeError: 'showit' object is not iterable
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Considerations:**

1. Writing a decorator that takes an optional argument needs to be done a bit differently than the way you have done it.
2. I am assuming you would like the `threaded` decorator to be able to support  both functions and methods if that is not to difficult to accomplish.

The decorated function/method can take as many positional and keyword arguments as you want (but at least one positional argument). When
you call the wrapped function the last positional argument must be
an iterable that will be used with the pool's `map` method.
All positional and keyword arguments will then be passed to the function/method when it is invoked as a worker function by `map` except that the last positional argument will now be an element of the iterable.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import wraps, partial

def threaded(poolsize=10):
    def outer_wrapper(fn):
        wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            """
            When the wrapper function is called,
            the last positional argument iterable will be an iterable
            to be used with the pool's map method.

            Then when map is invoking the original unwrapped function/method
            as a worker function, the last positional argument will be an element of
            that iterable.
            """

            # We are being called with an iterable as the first argument"
            # Construct a worker function if necessary:
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(poolsize) as executor:
                worker = partial(fn, *args[:-1], **kwargs)
                return list(executor.map(worker, args[-1]))
        return wrapper
    return outer_wrapper

iterable = [1, 2, 3]

@threaded(len(iterable))
def worker1(x, y, z=0):
    """
    y, the last positional argument, will be an iterable when the
    wrapper function is called or an element of the iterable
    when the actual, unwrapped function, worker1, is called.
    """
    return x + (y ** 2) - z

@threaded(3)
def worker2(x):
    return x.upper()

class MyClass:
    @threaded()
    def foo(self, x):
        return -x

# last positional argument is the iterable:
print(worker1(100, iterable, z=10))
print(worker2(['abcdef', 'ghijk', 'lmn']))
o = MyClass()
print(o.foo([3, 2, 1]))
```

Prints:

```None
[91, 94, 99]
['ABCDEF', 'GHIJK', 'LMN']
[-3, -2, -1]
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Exception reason:

When you say `a.again()`, Python creates a method object from the function `again` defined in your class. It's the behavior of a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

This means The first parameter of the `again` is gonna fill with the reference to the newly created `showit` object.

See the source code of the `map` method which you called in line `tp.map(fn, *args)`:

```py
    def map(self, fn, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1):
        ...
        ...
        fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
        ...
        ...
```

Look at the interested line, it's going to unpack `iterables` which currently is tuple of single item which is the instance of the `showit` class and pass it to `zip` function, `zip` accepts iterables and your `showit` instance is not. Too confirm add print statement to `wrapper` function:

```py
def threaded(fn, pools=10):
    tp = ThreadPoolExecutor(pools)

    def wrapper(*args):
        print(args)
        return tp.map(fn, *args)  # returns Future object

    return wrapper
```

##### How to fix it?

Actually what you're doing is a bit vague for me. I think maybe you don't need `concurrent.futures` package here. If your `again` method is supposed to run on it's own thread, you can do:

```py
import threading

id_str = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
id_int = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def threaded(fn):
    def wrapper(self):
        threading.Thread(target=fn, args=(self,)).start()

    return wrapper


class testit:
    def __init__(self, some_list):
        self._ids = some_list

    def test_first(self, some_id: list[int]):
        return some_id


class showit(testit):
    @threaded
    def again(self):
        for values in self.test_first(id_int):
            print(values)


a = showit(id_str)
a.again()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another update**

While the code in this answer works for the specific case outlined in above question, please use Booboo's answer instead, which is much more general (and just taught me a lot about decorators) and it also deals with the thread pool and its size lot better, because since all threads are now started inside the decorator, it makes sense to create a decorator-private thread pool again - like outlined in the question above.

**Updated answer!**

Based on your comment I believe this code should do, what you want (the problem is, that a method inside a class will always need to be called with self as the first parameter and that needs to be fed to tp.map as well):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import List

id_str = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
id_int = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
tp = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)

def threaded(fn):
    def wrapper(self,lst: List[int]):
        return tp.map(fn,[self]*len(lst),lst)
    return wrapper
    
class testit:
    def __init__(self, some_list: List[str]) -> None:
        self._ids = some_list
        print(self._ids)

    @threaded
    def test_first(self,some_id: int) -> int:
        return -some_id

class showit(testit):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(showit, self).__init__(*args)
    
    def again(self):
        global id_int
        for values in self.test_first(id_int):
            print(repr(values))

a = showit(id_str)
a.again()
```

But be aware: the original test_first method is receiving an int as as a parameter and the decorator is making that into a List[int] and takes care, that the original test_first method is called for each element of the list and doing that in parallel threads in the thread pool tp.

You can see that code in action at https://onlinegdb.com/gJxvgniGQ and it outputs:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
```

Comment: Great detail! The second example is what I am after however It needs to be wrapped up as a decorator - This I cannot figure out. If it works within the method, there should be a way to implement it as a decorator. BTW, my actual script already uses the second method because I cannot get the decorator. However, with multiple methods this becomes burdensome.

Comment: @Emil11 Okay... I updated my answer to use a decorator instead of using the tp.map directly.